# Can we add functionality to select multiple markup at a time in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, markup, autodesk-bim360, markup-extensions

I was stuck at the point in forge viewer, we are creating markup on the sheet, can we select multiple markup at a time so can we can delete or do other operation on that so is there any way to develop this multiple markup selection function.

In documentation i didn't found any function to handle multiple markup selection method.

If any one has idea please share!!!!

Thanks in Advance for the help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the `MarkupsCore` extension does not support multi-selection. We can submit a feature request internally but cannot guarantee if/when this will be implemented.